# How to replace last year's missing value with values from future years for a variable?

Tags: missing-data

I have a firm level longitudinal data for the years 2011, 2012, 2013 and 2014. There is a variable called 'Communication' which has values for all the years but due to changes in survey questions in 2012 and onwards, the corresponding values of that variable in 2011 unfortunately cannot be used in the analysis of the final data. If omitted, the whole 2011 series for that variable would be missing.

I was wondering if it is possible to use the values of 2012 to 2014 like simple average to fill in the column or values for the year 2011?

Comment: Can you paste in some sample data, ie before & after? Why can't the values be used?

Comment: The short answer is there are better things than the simple average. Can you give us a bit more detail about the model you will ultimately like to use?